# LSTM layers accepting any input shape when expecting them not to

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm building a neural network using keras and I'm a little lost on the LSTM layer input shape. Below is an image of the relevant part.

[image: Neural Network Part]

Both towers are similar with the only difference that the left accepts sequences of any length and the right only accepts sequences of length 5. This results in their LSTM layers receiving an ambiguous sequence length and a sequence length of 4 respectively, both with 8 features per timestep. I'd thus expect both LSTM layers should have an input_shape of (1,8).

My confusion now comes from the fact that both LSTM layers will accept any input shape without a problem, which is why I think this might not work the way I think it does. I'd expect the right LSTM layer to require an input shape with the first dimension either 1, 2 or 4 as only these sizes would be able to divide the input sequence of 4. Further, I'd expect both to require the second dimension to always be 8.

Could someone explain why the LSTM layers can accept any input shape and if they process the sequnces correctly with an input_shape=(1,8)? Below is the relevant code.

```
 # Tower 1
 inp_sentence1 = Input(shape=(None, 300, 1)) 
 conv11 = Conv2D(32, (2, 300))(inp_sentence1) 
 reshape11 = K.squeeze(conv11, 2)
 maxpl11 = MaxPooling1D(4, data_format='channels_first')(reshape11) 
 lstm11 = LSTM(units=6, input_shape=(1,8))(maxpl11)

 # Tower 2
 inp_sentence2 = Input(shape=(5, 300, 1)) 
 conv21 = Conv2D(32, (2, 300))(inp_sentence2) 
 reshape21 = Reshape((4,32))(conv21)
 maxpl21 = MaxPooling1D(4, data_format='channels_first')(reshape21) 
 lstm21 = LSTM(units=6, input_shape=(1,8))(maxpl21)
```

EDIT: Short reproduction of problem on dummy data:

```
    # Tower 1
    inp_sentence1 = Input(shape=(None, 300, 1))
    conv11 = Conv2D(32, (2, 300))(inp_sentence1)
    reshape11 = K.squeeze(conv11, 2)
    maxpl11 = MaxPooling1D(4, data_format='channels_first')(reshape11)
    lstm11 = LSTM(units=6, input_shape=(1,8))(maxpl11)

    # Tower 2
    inp_sentence2 = Input(shape=(5, 300, 1))
    conv21 = Conv2D(32, (2, 300))(inp_sentence2)
    reshape21 = Reshape((4,32))(conv21)
    maxpl21 = MaxPooling1D(4, data_format='channels_first')(reshape21)
    lstm21 = LSTM(units=6, input_shape=(1,8))(maxpl21)

    # Combine towers
    substract = Subtract()([lstm11, lstm21])
    dense = Dense(16, activation='relu')(substract)
    final = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(dense)

    # Build model
    model = Model([inp_sentence1, inp_sentence2], final)
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                   loss='binary_crossentropy',
                   metrics=['accuracy'])

    # Create data
    random_length = random.randint(2, 10)
    x1 = numpy.random.random((100, random_length, 300))
    x2 = numpy.random.random((100, 5, 300))
    y = numpy.random.randint(2, size=100)

    # Train and predict on data
    model.fit([x1, x2], y, epochs=10, batch_size=5)
    prediction = model.predict([x1, x2])
    prediction = [round(x) for [x] in prediction]
    classification = prediction == y
    print("accuracy:", sum(classification)/len(prediction))
```

Comment: Can you somehow make this reproducible with the data you have or, even better, with a simple toy example? Also, is this tf.keras with TF2?

Comment: @runDOSrun I've added a reproducible case. Yes this is keras using tensorflow v2.